# Streaming data from Android device to development PC

Tags: android, debugging, streaming, gnuplot, real-time-data

I am wondering how I can possibly stream data from an android device to my development PC. What I am actually trying to achieve is to stream some numerical data over to my PC and plot them in gnuplot in real-time.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

In a development environment, I assume your phone and PC are on the same network (wifi, or even via USB/ADB which can be used to relay network packets). If that is the case, simply write a TCP/IP server (or web application) that runs on your PC, and have your Android application connect to it and provide the data.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Realtime.co. No, I'm not trying to sell you anything. Just trying to help.

Another thing you can try is using a cross-platform communication layer such as [Realtime.co](http://www.realtime.co). It has an Android API as well as other APIs such as Java, PHP, .Net, iOS, JavaScript, etc.. So you can actually use it as your communication layer between your phone and any platform you need to be using on your computer (a browser, a Windows application, a Java, application, etc.).

I hope that helps!